# Ansible uri module being redirected to a "url not safe, if you are sure click proceed" site by proxy

Tags: curl, solr, proxy, ansible, wget

I'm using this role from ansible-galaxy to install solr.    `- role: geerlingguy.solr`.

This is my ansible task.

```
 hosts: all
  roles:
   - role: geerlingguy.solr
     solr_version: "5.5.4"
     solr_connect_host: localhost
  environment:
    "{{proxy_env}}"
```

In the process of installing, the runs a task

> "TASK [geerlingguy.solr : Check current list of Solr cores.] "

which uses the "uri" module to check if solr is running. However, since I'm using a proxy when "uri" makes a request to http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores uri gets back a 403 redirect to a

> "Caution this site is not verified and can expose you to malware,
>   viruses, and data loss, if you are sure you want to continue, click
>   "proceed"".

If I run `wget http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores` I don't get the redirect.

In my ansible task if I use the FQDN `"solr_connect_host: MyServersHostname.example.com"` the check being done by the uri module passes without issue.

I can't seem to reproduce the "caution please proceed" page issue with wget/curl. However, I assume that the proxy is what is causing the issue because using the FQDN works, that there must be some type of whitelist that allows.

How can I workaround this issue?

Comment: Is `localhost` in the `no_proxy` of your `proxy_env`?

Comment: @zigarn Nope. Wasn't aware of that...but that worked perfectly. I feel stupid now. If you want to write up that answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to have a `no_proxy` containing `localhost` in your environment `proxy_env`, otherwise the proxy will be used for localhost.